# Aligning background-image (:relative) to right

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have website where there is a header `background-image` that is styled with the following CSS:

```
.header {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 436px;
    background: url("../img/holland-canal.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

As it is now, when resizing the window on lower resolutions, the image is aligned to the left and thus the right part of the picture gets cut off. The right side of the picture contains the bridge, which I want to be visible at all times.

Is it possible to position the `background-image` in such a way that it is always aligned to the right, i.e. that the left part of the image is cut off when resizing to a smaller window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.header{
    background-position:right;
}
```

as the div that have the `header` class is containing the background image

Output

[image]

Fore more info, check **[this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)**

Answer (score 0):

Add `background-position`

```
.header {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 436px;
    background: url("../img/holland-canal.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: right;
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you